# how to initialize select box on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

i am using jquery select2 plugin its working fine but when i add select2 box on button click using function add_field it add the disabled select2 box.
here is my sample code

```
 <div id="divSelectContaioner">
        <div id="divSelect">
            <select class="e1" style="width: 200px;">
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="add_field">Add Field</button>
```

and js to add select2 box is

```
$(function() { 
        // initilizing the select box 
            $(".e1").select2(); 
            // add new select box
            $('#add_field').click(function(){
                $('#divSelectContaioner').append($('#divSelect').html());   
            });
        });
```

i am unable to figure out the problem. how can i do it??

Comment: Did you check browser console?

Comment: yes there is no error or waring.

Comment: i guess you have to activate the second select box the same way as the first one with .select2();

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: i am new newbie with this i have try to make it on fiddle but nothing hapen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$(function() { 
    // initilizing the select box 
        var select = $('.e1').clone();

        $(".e1").select2();

        // add new select box
        $('#add_field').click(function(){
            var newSelect = select.clone();
            $('#divSelectContaioner').append(newSelect);
            newSelect.select2();   
        });
    });
```

select2 plugin replaces your original select box with a custom html. So first of all we need to have a copy of original select:

```
var select = $('.e1').clone();
```

When you add a new select you get our original copy, make a copy again:) and initiate it with

```
newSelect.select2();
```

Comment: yes its working 10000000% perfect as i want Thank you but can't understated the last statement newSelect.select2();

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#add_field').click(function(){
    var $clonedSelect = $(".e1").clone(true);
    $('#divSelectContaioner').append($clonedSelect);   
    $clonedSelect.select2();
});
```

with [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) you create copy of element. If argument `true` is passed to it, it can copy both data and events of cloned element. It's better than using `$('#divSelect').html()`.

Comment: it creating the clone of only data but not event when i clicked on the cloned select box the original one is initiated

Comment: that's probably because of cloned element is having same class as origional element. Can you make fiddle out it?